# How to Filter a complex json object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

I have the following json object :

```
var json = {
    "Lofts": "none",
    "Maisons": "2",
    "HOMES": [{
        "home_id": "1",
        "price": "925",
        "num_of_beds": "2"
    }, {
        "home_id": "2",
        "price": "1425",
        "num_of_beds": "4",
    }, {
        "home_id": "3",
        "price": "333",
        "num_of_beds": "5",
    }]
};
```

How can I filter this object and remain with the HOMES property where home_id = 2 ?

Result:

```
var json = {
    "Lofts": "none",
    "Maisons": "2",
    "HOMES": [{
        "home_id": "2",
        "price": "1425",
        "num_of_beds": "4",
    }]
};
```

Is there any way I can cycle the object and mantein all the properties( also lofts and maisons)?

Thanks

Comment: Is the property `home_id` a unique value for all the objects of the `json.HOMES` array?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and assign the result directly to the property `HOMES`.

```js
var json = { "Lofts": "none", "Maisons": "2", "HOMES": [{ "home_id": "1", "price": "925", "num_of_beds": "2" }, { "home_id": "2", "price": "1425", "num_of_beds": "4", }, { "home_id": "3", "price": "333", "num_of_beds": "5", }] };

json.HOMES = json.HOMES.filter(function (a) {
    return a.home_id === '2';
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This was helpful, however I'm in a situation where I need to filter according to a list of attributes, stored in an array? More precisely, how would I modify the above if I wanted all homes with id's [1,2]? I tried `return a.home_id = ['1','2'];` but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @sc28, then you need to use either `indexOf` with a comparison, like `return ['1','2'].indexOf(a.home_id) !== -1;` or to check with `includes`, like `return ['1','2'].includes(a.home_id);`.

Answer (score 5):

With the use of utility library [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can use the method [find](https://lodash.com/docs#find) if `home_id` is unique.

**Find**: Iterates over elements of `collection` (Array|Object), returning the first element `predicate` returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

```
_.find(collection, [predicate=_.identity])
```

Code:

```js
var json = {"Lofts": "none","Maisons": "2","HOMES": [{"home_id": "1","price": "925","num_of_beds": "2"}, {"home_id": "2","price": "1425","num_of_beds": "4"}, {"home_id": "3","price": "333","num_of_beds": "5"}]};
json.HOMES = [_.find(json.HOMES, {home_id: '2'})];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If there are multiple objects with the same `home_id` you should make a [filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

`_.filter(collection, [predicate=_.identity])`

**Filter**: Iterates over elements of `collection` (Array|Object), returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

Code:

```js
var json = {"Lofts": "none","Maisons": "2","HOMES": [{"home_id": "1","price": "925","num_of_beds": "2"}, {"home_id": "2","price": "1425","num_of_beds": "4"}, {"home_id": "3","price": "333","num_of_beds": "5"}]};
json.HOMES = _.filter(json.HOMES, {home_id: '2'});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should actually use a filter, not a find, because the OP did specify a `where` clause (so by definition there might be more than one match). Also, there are much simpler matchers, both in lodash and in underscore: `_.where(json.HOMES, {home_id: "2"}` (http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) or `_.filter(json.HOMES, {home_id: "2"}` (https://lodash.com/docs#filter).